# How do I make a grid layout with one static column and one responsive column?

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a two column layout with a fixed width column on the left, and a responsive column which takes up the remaining space on the right. Here's an example:

```
<div>
  <div style="width:120px"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I've been working on this for a while now, but I can't seem to get it to work. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 CSS options with this markup:

```
<div>
  <div class="col1"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

option 1 :

```
div {
overflow:hidden;
border:solid;/* for demo */
}
.col1 {
width:120px;
float:left;
}
```

option 2 :

```
div {
display:table;
width:100%;
table-layout:fixed;
border:solid;/* for demo */
}
div div {
display:table-cell;
}
.col1 {
width:120px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! This worked. I think I'm going to go with your version as it keeps the divs. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple solution using No TABLES and table styles with `float` and `margin`:

```
.sidebar { 
    width: 200px; 
    float: left; 
}
.content { 
    margin-left: 200px; 
}
```

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/NrFLf/

Answer (score 0):

A table would better handle a grid layout, set the table @ 100%, put your static width for the left column @ 300px, and the right column will autofill the screen width.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/EEZqH/3/)

```
<table border=1 width=100%>
    <tr>
        <td width=300px>...Static Column</td>
        <td>...Dynamic Column.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Entry1</td>
        <td>Entry234189023452345</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Entry2</td>
        <td>You'll notice that the table cell only stretchs to the length of the text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Simple as that.

Comment: Thanks for your response! This worked perfectly. I think I'm going to go with @GCyrillus's version though, as it keep the divs.